# How to call $modal.open in Ui-Bootstrap 0.10.0 from controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to call `$modal.open` from controller in angular js. Previously in ui-bootstrap 0.1.0 dialog was there. Now in current version what is the privision to call your dialog.

in 0.1.0 it was just $dialog.dialog(); Then call to Dialog (); in Lib -

```
return {
  // Creates a new `Dialog` with the specified options.
   dialog: function(opts){
      return new Dialog(opts);
},

// creates a new `Dialog` tied to the default message box template and controller.
//
// Arguments `title` and `message` are rendered in the modal header and body sections respectively.
// The `buttons` array holds an object with the following members for each button to include in the

// modal footer section:

// * `result`: the result to pass to the `close` method of the dialog when the button is clicked

// * `label`: the label of the button
// * `cssClass`: additional css class(es) to apply to the button for styling

messageBox: function(title, message, buttons){
    return new Dialog({templateUrl: 'template/dialog/message.html', 
           controller: 'MessageBoxController', resolve: {model: {
      title: title,
      message: message,
      buttons: buttons
    }}});
}
```

Can any one know how to call $modal.open in 0.10.0 ?

Answer (score 6):

#### Set a function to do open:(set template, controller, resolve)

```
function open() {

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $scope.items;
    }
  }
});

});
```

#### Set modal controller:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

    $scope.items = items; 

});
```

#### And call it when you want:

```
open();
```

#### If you want to call from the template:

replace

```
function open() {
```

to

```
$scope.open = function() {
```

and call

```
$scope.open()
```

Comment: NB: if the template is in a file, it need to be in single quotes (```''```) in the resolve clause.